# Permutations and Groups in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove:  If $G$ is a group and $a \in G$, show that the two functions $l_a(x) = a * x$ and $r_a(x) = x * a$ are both *permutations* of $G$.

I know the definition of *permutation* is a function that maps from a set to itself that is both one to one and onto. This question that our professor has given us seems to be out of left field because we haven't been over mappings at all. Besides assuming the hypothesis of course, I'm not exactly sure where to begin on this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\in G$. You know by the definition of a group that every element has an inverse. Now define $l_a:G\to G$ by $l_a(x)=ax$. Assume $l_a(x)=l_a(y)$ for $x,y\in G$. Then $ax=ay$ and by multiplying both sides from the left side by the inverse $a^{-1}$ you get $x=y$. So $l_a$ is one to one. Now take any $y\in G$. Then $l_a(a^{-1}y)=aa^{-1}y=y$, so $l_a$ is also onto. Now do the same thing for $r_a$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $S$ is a set, $f : S\to S$ is a permutation if and only if $f$ admits an inverse function $g : S\to S$ such that $f\circ g = \operatorname{id}_S = g\circ f.$ Can you find inverses to your functions $l_a,r_a : G\to G$?